Expandable random oracle
I need a way to publicly expand a number in $\mathbb Z_q$ to a vector in $\mathbb Z_q^{n}$ in a random way. Normally, I could just use a PRG if I wanted to expand my input using a secret seed. However my use case needs to be such that anyone can compute this expansion.
I am wondering if I can justify being able to do this with a random oracle. By definition of a random oracle, it seems to be the tool I need for my construction. However, I have only seen random oracles compressing their inputs, rather than expanding them. Moreover even if I can use a random oracle, is this doable in practice?
Thank you for any help!

Yes, this is possible. One way to do this is by utilizing domain separation.
Domain separation ensures that two outputs of a hash function $H$ (assuming the random oracle model, ROM) are independent. We can separate the domains by appending a unique value. For example, we can differentiate the computation of two hash functions by $H(x \mathbin\Vert 0)$ and $H(x \mathbin\Vert 1)$, where $\Vert$ denotes concatenation. Both outputs are independent (only collide with negligible probability assuming big enough domain sizes).
If we now assume a hash function $H : \mathbb{Z}_{q+\lg n} \to \mathbb{Z}_q$, you can construct an expansion function $E : \mathbb{Z}_q \to \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ as
$$
E(x) = H(x \mathbin\Vert 0) \mathbin\Vert H(x \mathbin\Vert 1) \mathbin\Vert \dotsb \mathbin\Vert H(x \mathbin\Vert n-1).
$$

Or, you can just use SHAKE for the expansion function, and skip the repeated hashes.

Nice! Thanks for the construction!
